# onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', but only when running devtools::check()

Tags: r, devtools, rjava

I'm building an R package that uses some functionality from the `xlsx` package, and therefore the `rJava` package.

I have no trouble calling `library(xlsx)` or for that matter `library(rJava)` manually, and all my function code works just fine.  The problem occurs when I run `devtools::check()` on the package itself -- when it's checking the package, it halts with

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for 'towercount':
 .onLoad failed in loadNamespace() for 'rJava', details:
  call: fun(libname, pkgname)
  error: JAVA_HOME cannot be determined from the Registry
```

I've tried reinstalling Java, and I'm running 64-bit versions of both Java and R.  I've also tried setting JAVA_HOME manually with

`Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME='C:/Program Files/Java/jre1.8.0_191')`

and also with `Sys.setenv(JAVA_HOME="")`

I've also tried updating the `devtools` package.

Any suggestions?  Thanks for any help -